# Checking validation success from bean

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

Is there a valid way if i can check if primefaces required attribute validation has succeeded from inside the bean ? 
The validation allready works but i need to check that to store and use in other beans.

Comment: Have a look at java validation framework: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

Comment: @Juned: how exactly does that help OP's concrete problem? Or are you merely shooting in the dark? Please don't do that, it would only misguide/mislead the OP. If you're merely guessing, please explicitly say that so. E.g. "I'm not sure, but perhaps JSR303 Bean Validation framework has a solution for you?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the specific [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) component instance from the view by [`UIViewRoot#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) and then check its [`isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) outcome.

```
UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
UIInput input = (UIInput) view.findComponent("formId:inputId");
boolean valid = input.isValid();
// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there's most likely a much better way for the concrete functional requirement for which you possibly incorrectly thought that *this* would be the right solution. Unfortunately, as you didn't state that anywhere in the question, it's not possible to post an answer for that.